# Filter only "Easy Apply" jobs in Stack Overflow Jobs listings

Tags: support, feature-request, status-review, stack-overflow-jobs

I want a way to see only jobs which can be applied directly through stackoverflow, means no need to first go to indeed or any other website in order to apply.

If it is already implemented then please some-one tell me how to access that feature.
If not then I think it should be implemented.